# PySpark reserved words or something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Is there a problem with using value as column name in pyspark?

I'm getting this error:

```
An error occurred while calling o953.pyWriteDynamicFrame. syntax error in attribute name: manualReviewReasons[struct].value
```

Comment: Maybe `struct`?

Comment: Do you have '.' in your column name? If yes remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be data schema that was saved into data catalog was causing problems. If you have schema that has empty object or empty name property it will fail :/